# On Import, why did Magento delete products?

Tags: magento2.3.1, import-products

I did a product import with behaviour REPLACE using the backend.

The original reason to do this is, that we get duplicated images when importing a CSV file with same products again.

[image: Replace product data - Settings]

If I understand [the documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import.html) correctly, this *does* replace the full data of an SKU which is in the import file. But it leaves products with SKUs which are not in the import file untouched.

> If a SKU in the import data matches the SKU of an existing entity, all
>   fields, including the SKU are deleted, and a new record is created using the CSV data. An error occurs if the CSV file references a SKU that does not exist in the database. You can Check Data to display error.

In as test with only two products, this turned out to be true -- not all other products were lost.

But on my recent - real - import it showed:

[image: import results]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to count all the products which were deleted to be replaced by new data as "deleted here".

*Leads me to [a new bonus question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273712/is-there-a-better-way-than-replace-behavior-during-the-import-to-avoid-duplic)*