# is there a better way than "replace" behavior during the import, to avoid duplicated images

Tags: magento2.3.1, product-import, firegento-extendedimport2

We import products using CSV files via the backend. `FireGento_ExtendedImport2` is installed as well.

Now we saw that images are added again and again to a product's image gallery on each import.

We tried using the [replace behavior](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273710/on-import-why-did-magento-delete-products/273711#273711) which seems solves this at first  glance --- but I feel it is ineffective to re-create thousands of products again and again.

Is there another way to avoid duplication of images during repeated imports?